# Problem calculating a limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to examine the limits of the [Total Compton Cross section](https://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/personalhomes/frieger/HEA7.pdf) (pag. 14) in the relativistic and non relativistic limits, and I'm having struggles with simple limits, which is very discouraging, by the way. The equation is the following:

$$\frac{\sigma_e}{\sigma_T} = \frac{3}{4} \left\{\frac{1+x}{x^3}\left[\frac{2x(1+x)}{1+2x} - \ln{(1+2x)}\right] + \frac{\ln{(1+2x)}}{2x} - \frac{1+3x}{(1+2x)^2}\right\}$$

when $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sigma_e}{\sigma_T}$ the very first term is proportional to

$$\frac{1+x}{1+2x}\frac{2(1+x)}{x^2} = 2\frac{(1+x)^2}{(1+2x)x^2}$$
which is a grade 3 polynomial dividing a 2nd grade one. Inmediately this yields $\infty$ and I know this shouldn't be happening (the expression would diverge and be meaningless in the context of what I am studying, also I verified the result of $1$ in Mathematica).

The only alternative would be that the complete expression is of the form $\infty + \mathrm{terms} \sim 1$ but this sounds weird to me.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The term $-\frac{1+3x}{(1+2x)^2}$ also diverges for $x\to0$ so you can't separate the first and second terms

Comment: Don't ignore the logarithm. $$\frac{2x(1+x)}{1+2x} - \log (1 + 2x)$$ vanishes of higher order at $0$.

Comment: You can only take apart the terms of a limit and evaluate their limits separately if these limits actually exist. Individual limits may not exist even when the composite limit does. For example, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x,\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x}x$ do not exist but their difference does: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}x=0$.